# What is a good approach/language/tool to use for auto from submission and then export result into excel

Tags: c#, html, excel, selenium

So say I have a large amount of data (around 2000 entries). each entry contains 4-5 values that are used to enter into a web form. Once submitted, the returned result is then displayed from the website in html. Usually it returns a number.

I have all these entries stored in a excel sheet, and I want to check the results of those entries every day. I hope to automate the process so it can automatically update the values based on the returned results from the form. Ideally i want then export those returned values out of the html and back into excel. Right now I do it manually by using a web browser.

I am a seasoned embedded programmer but have no web experience. I suppose I can use some type of libraries and C#, but before I start busting out the big guns, I hope I can get some pointers on what language/tools I can use for this problem. I was looking into selenium but it seems that its used for testing rather than automation.

Comment: Why are you storing data in an excel file, and not a Database?

Comment: Is data stored on SQL DB?

Comment: because this is just a very simple personal project. data is stored in excel. or I can export it in whatever format. (i do not want to use a DB)